# Tmux borders has two colors on mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux, color-scheme

[image]

You see the first half is black and the second half is green.

How ugly!

Can you help me?

Comment: That's intentional; green on the bottom means the right-hand pane is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors are controlled by pane-border-fg and pane-active-border-fg, if you set them to the same color, you get the same color. For example:

```
set-option -g pane-border-fg green
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg green
```

After tmux 2.9 these are controlled by :

```
set-option -g pane-border-style fg=green
set-option -g pane-active-border-style fg=green
```